# Updating TextView on a delay after a button press

Tags: android, textview, delay, runnable

I am trying to update a TextView at intervals of five seconds at a time after a button press, but when the application is run, the TextView will only display the last values of the loop that it is being run in.

Here is what I am trying:

```
private Runnable textUpdate = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);

        textOutput.setText("Reading Number " + (rIndex+1) + "\n");
        textOutput.append(sensorTime[rIndex] + "\n");
        textOutput.append("Value: " + rPoint.getValue() + "\n");
    }
};
```

...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    TextView textOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
    textOutput.setText("Simulation output:\n");

    Button button03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button03);
    button03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                rIndex = i;
                rPoint = dp[i];

                mHandler.postDelayed(textUpdate, 5000);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Cannot understand why only the last value of the information I am trying to output is being displayed in the TextView.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I see is on your last line of code:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(textUpdate, 5000);
```

You're posting all your updates at 5000 milliseconds, each starting milliseconds apart (as fast as the phone can loop).

Try this instead:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(textUpdate, i * 5000);
```

Comment: Ah!  One thing solved.  I do see now it is now posting it every five seconds, but something else in my code must be errant because it is updating with only the last value repeatedly.

Comment: Figured out what I needed changed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can make the runnable post itself again.

```
private Runnable textUpdate = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);

        textOutput.setText("Reading Number " + (rIndex+1) + "\n");
        textOutput.append(sensorTime[rIndex] + "\n");
        textOutput.append("Value: " + rPoint.getValue() + "\n");

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

then remove all messages in onPause

Comment: that's why you have to remove the runnable in `onPause` or so (`mHandler.removeCallbacks(textUpdate);`)